# python: os.chdir - recursive error

Tags: python

I want to iterate through a directory that has 3 folders, each one of them containing images. The construction is like this:

```
- src
-- main.py
- data
-- train
--- Type_1
--- Type_2
--- Type_3
```

My code is like this:

```
for t in [1, 2, 3]:

    #load_files
    os.chdir("../data/train/Type_" + str(t))
    files = glob.glob("*.jpg")
    no_files = len(files)

    #iterate and read
    for n, file in enumerate(files):
        try:
            print (file, t, "-files left", no_files -n)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(file)
```

But after it finishes iterating through *Type_1*, I get an error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joasa/src/main.py", line 33, in <module>
os.chdir("../data/train/Type_" + str(t))
 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '../data/train/Type_2'
```

Comment: Is `Type_2` a directory ?

Comment: You don't have to do this manually,  Have a look into pathlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: yes, it's a folder containing images, just like type_1 and type_3. these 3 folders are located in another folder called train, just like the construction diagram i show above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `chdir()` which changes the working directory of your entire program.  Just pass paths directly:

```
glob.glob(os.path.join("..", "data", "train", "Type_{}".format(t), "*.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 2):

See @John's answer for a more suitable approach - don't `chdir()` unless you actually need to.

I feel that my answer still has some relevance, so I'm leaving it - see below.

---

You're using relative paths, which is probably asking for trouble in this scenario.

Follow along below (it's not going to work):

- `/home/joasa/my_project/`
- `/home/joasa/data/train/Type_1/`
- `/home/joasa/data/train/data/train/Type_2/`
- `/home/joasa/data/train/data/train/data/train/Type_3/`

I would advise that you make this act on absolute paths, like below:

```py
import os

start_dir = os.getcwd()

for t in [1, 2, 3]:
    this_dir_rel = "../data/train/Type_%d" % ( t )
    this_dir_abs = os.path.join(start_dir, this_dir_rel)
    os.chdir(this_dir_abs)
```